# getting an import error after pip installing djcelery

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm following the [starting with Django for Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) tutorial.
pip installed everything in the virtualenv (activated)

and have the following structure:

```
project folder/
    dev.db
    manage.py
    app.one/ #app folder
    celeryapp # a folder that contains the files from the tutorial.
    /__init__.py
    /celery.py #as explained in the tutorial
    projectname/ #folder that contains settings.py, urls etc.
```

My problem, after installing `djcelery` and adding it to django `INSTALLED_APPS`, everything that touches django runserver fails with:

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'register.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named celery
```

using 3.1.6

the celery.py is as follows:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env/python
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os

from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE','register.settings')

app = Celery('celery')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

@app.task(bind = True)
def debug_task(self):
  print ('Request: {0!r} '.format(self.request))
```

Any ideas? links? how can solve this problem..

Thanks for the help

Comment: Try `./manage.py runserver --traceback`, and provide us with the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

I think your celery.py module is shadowing the real celery library.

In the tutorial they have their celery.py in "proj/proj/celery.py" and are using:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

To make sure that they don't end up re-importing the same file again.

You basically need to move your celery.py somewhere else (e.g. inside projectname I think).